# What is the main reason to prefer Frame Layout

Tags: android, layout

I am new in android. I learnt different layouts. But I am not realizing Why would I exactly prefer Frame layout instead of Relative Layout ?

Comment: Check this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In framelayout we can have multiple view over one another. 
It will help you create overlay designs.

Frame layout is used when you want to show one item on each screen. Using frame layout, we can have multiple items, but they will be overlapping and only only displaying themselves one at a time.

FrameLayout is particularly useful when you want to create animation or movement on screen.

Comment: blganesh101@ Thank you for your reply. Is it the only reason to choose  Frame layout or not.

Answer (score 3):

@blganesh101's accepted answer does not really answer the question.

`RelativeLayout` by default lays out its contents like `FrameLayout` i.e. on top of each other unless `RelativeLayout`'s more advanced layout attributes like `layout_toRightOf` are used. Therefore you can use a `RelativeLayout` everywhere you are using a `FrameLayout`.

The main reason for preferring `FrameLayout` is performance. Since it does not really do any layout, its implementation is very simple and it runs faster than the more complicated layouts. Of course, if you don't need the `FrameLayout` at all, it's best to leave it out altogether.

`FrameLayout` is also often used as a simple container for dynamically added content such as `Fragment`s.

Comment: thank you laalto for your more information.